# Contour matching

Tags: c#, matching, contour

I'm having two contours, one given as a set of points and the other given as a set of lines and arcs. What is the best way to compare the two contours, in C#? I have already compared the convex hulls of the two contours, so I'm trying to refine the match for the rest of the features.

Comment: You can use `System.Drawing` to draw your contours, one on the left and one on the right for a simple visual comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` class has intersting methods which could be helpful for you.

`IsOutlineVisible` with various overloads tests if a point lies on the path's outline. `IsVisible` tests if a point lies inside of a closed path.

Comment: The set of points involved in the matching result from an acquisition process that may introduce a certain noise. You are right, GraphicsPath seems to be a good solution for an exact matching, but I am looking for some metrics to allow a certain amount of distortion.

Comment: You can specify a pen that has a certain width. The point must lie on the line that would be drawn by that pen.